# Meta Boxes: 'admin_init' or 'add_meta_boxes' hook?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, admin-menu

When setting up meta boxes in a custom post type I've been do so using the `add_meta_boxes` hook, e.g.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'meta_box_setup');
function meta_box_setup()
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'mb_movie_review', 
        'Movie Review Details', 
        'display_movie_review_mb', 
        'movie-reviews', 
        'side', 
        'high' 
    );
}
```

But I've just read [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes/) which does the following using the `admin_init` hook, like so...

```
add_action('admin_init', 'meta_box_setup');
function meta_box_setup()
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'mb_movie_review', 
        'Movie Review Details', 
        'display_movie_review_mb', 
        'movie-reviews', 
        'side', 
        'high' 
    );
}
```

This is the first time I've seen it done using the `admin_init` hook.

**Question**

The latter method (using `admin_init`) **does** work but ...

- is this the ***preferred*** method? (i.e. more optimized?)
- just a ***different*** way of achieving the same results, or
- a **bad** way to add meta boxes? (if so, why?)

Comment: Have a look at this list: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference - it doesn't matter which one you use as long as it's not too early and not too late. It's best to use intuitive and predictable hooks, so `add_meta_boxes` is preferred.

Comment: @Paul Great. Can you post this as an answer (so I can credit you)?

Comment: Agreed, I think that simply the tutorial author was not aware of `add_meta_boxes`. We have even `"add_meta_boxes_$post_type"` for finer control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this list: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

1. It doesn't matter which one you use as long as it's not too early and not too late. It's best to use intuitive and predictable hooks, so `add_meta_boxes` is preferred. Someday in the future WordPress may change something and by using the most appropriate hooks you increase your chances that your code will still work in the future.
2. There is one exception that I can think of to that. Sometimes (in cases that are very unlikely to happen) you may need to for instance call `add_theme_support()` which is generally used with `after_setup_theme` action hook only for logged in users that are administrators but this hook doesn't allow you to access this information yet. You would therefore have to probably use `set_current_user` or `init` action hooks instead (after doing some research if it's safe to do that).

Answer (score 3):

There are several other hooks:

```
do_action( 'add_meta_boxes', $post_type, $post );
```

and immediately afterwards runs:

```
do_action( "add_meta_boxes_{$post_type}", $post );
```

If you want to perform different abort checks from within the hook/callback that actually registers the meta boxes, use one of the above as the `\WP_Screen` object isn't filled as early as `admin_init` runs.

If you used the more generic `add_meta_boxes` hook, you can check against its first argument:

```
function register( $post_type, $post )
{
    if ( get_current_screen()->post_type !== $post_type )
        return;

    add_meta_box( /* etc. */ );
}
```

If you don't want to add your meta box as long as the post hasn't been saved at least once, you could check

```
if ( 'add' !== get_current_screen()->action )
    return;
```

and so on. Conclusion: If you want to narrow things down, use the hooks shown above.